# Lua random number generation

Tags: for-loop, random, lua

I am having trouble with the **math.random()** function in Lua.
The code I'm trying to run is:

```
 for x = 1,5 do
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    math.random(); math.random(); math.random()
    value = math.random(0,9)
    print(value)
end
```

The random number that is being printed is always the same.

What can be the possible solution to this? I want 5 unique random numbers.

Comment: put `math.randomseed(os.time())` *out* of the loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize random *once* (outside the loop), use *many*:

```
math.randomseed(os.time()) -- random initialize
math.random(); math.random(); math.random() -- warming up

for x = 1,5 do
    -- random generating 
    value = math.random(0,9)
    print(value)
end
```

Comment: the three calls to warm up the generator don't need to be *in* the loop either, but [do serve a purpose](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial)

Comment: @rpattiso: Thank you! I see

Comment: @shiladitya basu Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)