# How do i make a variable have random numbers that are strings every time the code is run

Tags: lua

I am attempting to make a guessing game in Lua i have did everything else the only thing I need to do now is make it generate random numbers that are strings in a variable called answer every time the code is run.

this is the code I have right now `answer = math.randomseed(1, 100)(os.time())`the problem i have is that i need it to come up with a number that is a string, 1-100, random every time the code is run and for it to be put into the variable answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784489/randomseed-in-lua

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355654/lua-random-number-generation)

Answer (score 1):

```
local ans = tostring(math.random(1,100))
print(ans)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make it generate new every time? since everytime the code is run it comes out with 85 and since it is a guessing game i cant have the same number each time

Comment: @hassan As far as I know, now you'd only have to put e.g. `math.randomseed(os.time())` at some point before generating the random number (just above declaring the `ans` variable in the given example) to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.format()` to put what you want out as a String.

```lua
local seed = math.randomseed(math.random(os.time()))
local fmt = ('%d'):format(math.random(1, 100))

print(type(fmt), fmt:rep(10, ' > '))
-- Example output: string   99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99 > 99
```

Than make a Function

```
local seed = math.randomseed(math.random(os.time()))

local function rn(mini, maxi)
  local mini, maxi = mini or 1, maxi or 6 -- No Arguments defaults to a Dice
  return(('%d'):format(math.random(mini, maxi)))
end

for i = 1, 10 do print(type(rn(1, 100)), rn(1, 100)) end
```

Output Example

```
string  56
string  75
string  86
string  98
string  35
string  36
string  81
string  33
string  1
string  23
```

Comment: Call math.randomseed exactly once in your program, not every time you need a random number

Answer (score 0):

I made a random number game and my code was "math.randomseed(os.time())

```
local secret_number = math.random(1, 100)
  print("guess what the number is, 1-100")
  repeat
    local guess_number = io.read("*n")
    if not guess_number then print("invalid input!")
   elseif guess_number < secret_number then print("too low, try again!")
   elseif guess_number > secret_number then print("too high, try again!") 
 end
 until guess_number == secret_number
 print("you got it!! congrats")
```